# How to manage questions with the exact same title?

Tags: discussion, title

Can you have a look to the following questions? They have exactly the same title.

[How are extension methods compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932090/extension-methods)

[Why are "static" and "this" needed for extension methods, and how is their memory allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730013/extension-methods)

[Why is my extension method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770518/extension-method)

[Why can't I use LINQ methods on my class implementing IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893395/extension-methods)

Of course I can edit the title of each question to differentiate and make it better clarificative; but maybe it would be more useful to implement a feature suggesting people to write a *better* title in case of exactly identical title with other questions.

What's your opinion on that?

Comment: The site won't let you post a question with the exact same title, or edit the title so there are two exactly the same. Apparently it's case-sensitive though. This seems like it could be a bug.. Exactly the same title usually suggests that the question is a duplicate, too.

Comment: @3ventic: in this case I think the title is so short that the question may be completely different, however the title seems to be not of good quality.

Comment: @Stijn: it's not a duplicate, since there are 2 different "bugs".. On punctuation and on uppercase. Also I suggest one solution and he suggests another. However if you think it's worth to merge it the two questions, it would be appreciable you can show a constructive effort and merge them.